# What is the best way to retain lost focus in angularjs (due DOM updates)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, repeater

I have repeater in which buttons are used.
On those button the array which is used in same repeater is modified (items are added or removed).
Thus focus is lost from a certain button when array is being updated.
In such cases what will be the best way to retain focus on freshly created respective DOM element.

Comment: just store the button id then refocus after it changes

Comment: `ng-init` with the `ng-repeat` might work. If `ng-init` calls an expression checking if the button should have the focus if true give the button focus again.

Comment: @GabrielGates This solution is not suitable for my current code.
It will refocus every time controller is initialized.

Comment: Could you add an example in Plunker for us play with?